# Alternative to GET and POST methods to send/recieve data from a form

Tags: php, web-applications, mod-rewrite, http-post

I am trying to build a web application in PHP.

But I dont want to use the GET & POST methods, as user shall know what and how are we sending the data, just by looking at the html end. Of course we can always sanitize the data, but still, I want to keep the format of data to myself.

Is there an alternative to the above...

can something be done with the url, so that the type and format of data is not revealed. I saw something in this regard that related to mod rewrite.

Please suggest and tell me if I am on the right track.

Comment: those are the main methods, and other methods are just a variation of the same methods

Comment: You need to read the HTTP 1.1 specification in regards to HTTP Request GET / POST, I think you're lacking some fundamental knowledge.

Comment: you are on the right track :)

Comment: I do not know about anything with regard to `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what other people are putting here,  you can in some respects do what you like, although it wont accomplish your goal:

PUT / SEARCH / DELETE are all concepts of a RESTful interface

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

If you wanted to be inventive ... create a new one called `HIDEFROMUSER` and configure your webserver and PHP script to accept this in the headers.  Note, most, if not all browsers wont support this, but a jquery ajax call should...

```
 header('Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, HIDEFROMUSER', true, 405);

 $accept = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
 // does $accept equal one of your allowed methods?
```

Finally `$yourHiddenWayOfDoingThings = fopen('php://input', 'r');`

People will still see what you're doing **if it works** and you wont have achieved your expectations...

Answer (score 3):

You are not on the right track.

You cannot really hide the way data is sent, because the browser has to know somehow, and if it knows, the possible intruder will know. Use GET and POST as you normally would, filter and sanitize user data. That's the best you can do.

You can even change the URL, but the browser will still have it, so will the possible intruder.

If you are going for something more secure, HTTPS seems to be a good option for you.

Answer (score 2):

GET and POST are your only options. Additionally, your script should not be dependant on user ignorance of how it works for security, that's like leaving your house unlocked on the grounds that people usually don't try random doors to see if they're unlocked.  Security by obscurity is doomed to fail.

Comment: +1 security by obscurity is certainly not the way (or certainly not the thing to start with, some say it can be added as an additional layer - some say it is worthless)

Comment: Like I said, my analogy is it's like leaving your door unlocked on the grounds that most people don't go around trying doors at random.

Comment: I agree that sanitizing the data is needed for security, I just wanted to hide the data in the frontend as well.

Answer (score 0):

only suggestion I can offer would be to hide the HTML, eg, if you used flash/silverlight or java, the user cant access even field names of the form, page destinaiton of the processing page etc. You could also then if necessary do some form of data manipulation so you sent data= and the other end, undo the manipulation and parse it out, but of course anything that can be unparsed, is open to attack if someone snoops the network data and spends enough time working out the way you manipulated it.

Comment: The methods you offer only protect against people who would not be able to do anything with this data (if they could get it) anyways.

Comment: Flash and java wouldn't solve the problem as there's packet sniffers and decompilers, and they'd introduce a roadblock to accessibility.

Comment: @GordonM Exactly what I was trying to say :).

Comment: GordonM, I did say, that anyone snooping network data would see it. There isnt a lot to be done to hide this.