# Apart from GET and POST is there any way to send data to server using PHP?

Tags: php, forms

Can I send data to web server without using get or post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464005/alternative-to-get-and-post-methods-to-send-recieve-data-from-a-form

Comment: If you're using HTTP, apart from `PUT`, no. What are you trying to do? We need more details if you want an answer that's actually useful.

Comment: I want to send some data from a device to server and save it in database, but I do not want to use get or post

Comment: If you *want* to talk to a **web server** without using HTTP protocol (GET / POST) then you're doing something very, very, very wrong.

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use GET or POST? Allergies?

Comment: I want to talk to server using GET/POST but I do not want to send data via them

Comment: Without trying to offend you, how come you get to work with a technology you don't really understand? Web server knows only how to receive data using HTTP protocol, which is sending data using either POST or GET. You don't want to use it (for some mysterious, unknown reason) - therefore, you can't talk to the server at all. It's as simple as that. Rethink what you want to achieve, it's obvious you're doing something wrong.

Comment: No I do not have any Allergies I want my data to be secured as it will be device location in that request

Comment: Why don't you say from the beginning that you're talking about ***security***?! Use ***HTTPS***, the SSL secured variant of HTTP. You need no more.

Comment: It is really getting confusing my question is, if I send some data to server in query string for eg: ../set_data.php?var1=123&var2=abc then these variables are accessible on server as $_GET['var1'] and $_GET['var2'] similarly for POST if we post them to server by using $_POST['var1'] and $_POST['var2']. Now is there any mechanism apart from them to send data to server.

Comment: Look at what an HTTP request looks like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Http_request_telnet_ubuntu.png There's nowhere else to transport data, you only have the *headers* which includes the URL (which becomes `$_GET` in PHP) and the *body* (which becomes `$_POST`). All of it is equally secure/insecure.

Comment: Thankyou @deceze now I am clear with the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really understand what GET/POST means. It's just a "verb" in the HTTP headers. You are not actually "sending data via POST", that's just a short way to say *"you are making an HTTP request with the POST verb in the header and arbitrary data in the body"*. "Sending data via GET" is a conventional way to say *"making an HTTP request using the GET verb in the header and putting some data into the URL"*.

You can send any data in the body you wish and get the raw bytes like:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

If you're using HTTP, you always have to use one of the HTTP verbs, GET and POST are the most obvious to use. If you want to avoid HTTP, make up any custom protocol you want using sockets, but you should have a real reason to do so.

Comment: I am asking if I send some data to server in query string for eg: ../set_data.php?var1=123&var2=abc then these variables are accessible on server as $_GET['var1'] and $_GET['var2'] similarly for POST if we post them to server by using $_POST['var1'] and $_POST['var2']. Now is there any mechanism apart from them to send data to server.

Comment: That's really a misnomer of PHP. `$_GET` data is data from the URL's *query string*. `$_POST` data is data from the *HTTP request body* which was sent query string encoded. You can get both by manually parsing the URL from `$_SERVER` or by getting the request body as shown in my answer and again parsing it manually. What else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

No. There isn't. You can do all sorts of things to hide or cleanse your GET and POST data, but that's about it really.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies, arbitrary HTTP headers and message bodies in non-POST requests (such as an HTTP PUT).

Answer (score -1):

The post and get data are added to the header of your request and php parse them automatically.

You can manually add anything you want to the header using ajax and fetch it in php with getallheaders().